# Common Lisp Defensive Copy of Values

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am wondering whether there is a built-in way to do a defensive copy of a values list type in Common Lisp. It is my understanding that this list is not a regular list, but is some reserved type.

I suppose one solution is to convert to a proper list, make a copy of that and then convert it back to the values list. However, I am unsure of the most efficient way to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Multiple values are not first-class objects, they're just a way of passing values out of a function. If you want to capture them, the only way is to convert to a list.

Comment: Is there a way to do that if the arity is variable? That is, it seems that I need the inverse of `values-list` that will take a `VALUES` output and make a proper list from it.

Comment: [`MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_mult_1.htm)

Comment: A values list is just as an argument list on a function call only the way back. It's most likely values on a stack and you cannot use it without one of the forms that deal with multiple values. It is to avoid consing when you can pass more than one value between calls. It's a micro optimization to reduce consing.

Comment: What you want to do serves no possible purpose: whatever secret data structure lies behind multiple values is not accessible to you, and in particular there no operations which can mutate it: 'defensively copying it' makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

The entire purpose and effect of the *multiple values* mechanism in Common Lisp is to allow transferring more than one value back from a form *without consing*, i. e. without wrapping another temporary object around them.

Under the hood, you can imagine those values to reside directly on the stack or even in registers.

For example, if you have such a function:

```
(defun foo ()
  (values 1 2))
```

and you call it like this:

```
(multiple-value-bind (a b) (foo)
  (+ a b))
```

then 1 gets assigned to `a` and 2 to `b` directly, without first putting anything into any kind of intermediate structure.

There is thus no such thing as a *values* object, nor a single place to hold *values*, so there can also be no type or anything like that associated with it.

I don't see how a “defensive” copy might be needed, but you can wrap things received as values into a list using [`multiple-value-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_mult_1.htm#multiple-value-list), return things in a list as multiple values using [`values-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vals_l.htm#values-list), or set multiple places to the values returned from some form using [`multiple-value-setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_mult_2.htm#multiple-value-setq) or [`(setf values)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_abc.htm).